# Need to create a chart using a MySQL table in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to make a dynamic table using the following table. It doesn't matter whether it's from ChartJS or Google Chart. I need to take "Blood Types" for the Y axis as labels and for the X axis I need to take the number of rows for the each blood type where "isAvailable" equals 1.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEtbx.png)

I tried above way, it gets the data to the view but need to rewrite the code for each blood type so it is not very efficient. I need to know is there any better way?

Controller

```
public function bloodTypesChart()
    {
        $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(PacketID) as count,(BloodType) as blood_type FROM packets WHERE (isAvailable) = '1'");

        $packetCount = $this->db->count_all_results();

        $record = $query->result();
        $chartData = [];

        foreach($record as $row) {
            $chartData['label'][] = 'O+';
            $chartData['data'][] = $packetCount;
        }
        $chartData['chart_data'] = json_encode($chartData);
        $this->load->view('insight',$chartData);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better and a simple solution. Avoided using php loops to get data.

```
public function bloodTypesChart()
    {
        $query=" SELECT BloodType as blood_type, COUNT(PacketID) as mycount 
            FROM packets 
            WHERE isAvailable = 1 
            GROUP BY blood_type
         ";    

        $chartData = [];
        $blood_types = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

        foreach($blood_types as $row)
        {
                $chartData['label'][] = $row['blood_type'];
                $chartData['data'][] = $row['mycount'];
        }
        $chartData['chart_data'] = json_encode($chartData);
        $this->load->view('insight',$chartData);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most efficient solution, but it is sure to get the job done for you right.

```php
public function bloodTypesChart()
{ 
   $totalPackets = $this->db->count_all_results();
 
   $chartData = [];
   $blood_types = $this->db->query("SELECT (BloodType) as blood_type FROM packets WHERE (isAvailable) = '1' GROUP BY blood_type")
                       ->result_array();

   foreach($blood_types as $bt)
   {
      $record =  $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(PacketID) as count FROM packets WHERE BloodType = '{$bt['blood_type']}'")
                      ->result_array();

      foreach($record as $row) {
         $chartData['label'][] = $bt['blood_type'];
         $chartData['data'][] = $row['count'];
      }
   }
$chartData['chart_data'] = json_encode($chartData);
$this->load->view('insight',$chartData);
}
```

**RECOMENDED:** You can also try something like this

```
$record =  $this->db->from('packets')
                ->select('count(PacketID) count, BloodType blood_type')
                ->group_by('blood_type')
                ->get()
                ->result_array();

foreach($record as $row) {
   $chartData['label'][] = $row['blood_type'];
   $chartData['data'][] = $row['count'];
}
```

Of course you could still use the query() method and manualy write your queries.

I have not tested any of these but it should give you an idea of where to go next.

Comment: Thank you @3m1n3n3 for your answer. This gives an error stating "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array". Do you know why?

Comment: I change the $record query to ```"SELECT COUNT(PacketID) as count WHERE BloodType = '$bt->blood_type'"``` and it gives an error saying ```SELECT COUNT(PacketID) as count WHERE BloodType = ''```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have made a few corrections to my answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you @3m1n3n3 but it still gives an error saying ```Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::getResultArray()```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I've modified again, try this time... Sorry I don't have an active CI project to test on.

Comment: Still gives the same error @3m1n3n3. I think the error is in the first `getResultArray()` function in `$blood_types = $this->db->query("SELECT (BloodType) as blood_type FROM packets WHERE (isAvailable) = '1' GROUP BY blood_type")->getResultArray();`

Comment: Are you using CI 3?

Comment: yes I am using CodeIgniter 3.

Comment: Sorry I really missed that, I had to setup a codeigniter 3 project so I could test this, I could not replicate your table structure, so if there is an error it is definitely a typo, I've tested it and it should work, let me know your observations and experience.

Comment: I changed `getResultArray()` to `result_array()` and now that error is gone but now it shows `SELECT COUNT(PacketID) as count WHERE BloodType = ''`

Comment: post a screenshot here [https://pic.li/](https://pic.li/)

Comment: here @3m1n3n3 this is the error I'm getting https://pic.li/i/gQ35
This is the code https://pic.li/i/gzjd is there any issue with it?

Comment: Ok so aparently, we were missing this clause from our query: `FROM packets`. You can look at the modified answer to see were it goes. I would also recommend using the second solution in order to avoid the nested loops and take advantage of a performace boost.

Comment: Hell yes! Thank you very much @3m1n3n3! Now it works. There are minor issues but I think I will be able to solve those.